# NULL value for "System.Int32"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I read book "ASP.NET MVC5" by Freeman and I try to add administration page to my site. Now when I go to the page *http://localhost:63843/Admin/Edit*, I have error:

*Dictionary of the parameters contains an entry with a NULL value for the parameter "productId" type "System.Int32", not allowing the value NULL, the method for "System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult Edit (Int32)" in "SportsStore.WebUI.Controllers.AdminController". An optional parameter must be a reference type, type, allowing the value NULL, or it must be declared as an option.
Parameter name: parameters*

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository repository;

    public AdminController(IProductRepository repo) {
        repository = repo;
    }

    public ViewResult Edit(int productId) {
        Product product = repository.Products
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
        return View(product);
    }
}
```

But here is all references to Edit and there is no any NULL value:

```
Product p1 = target.Edit(1).ViewData.Model as Product;
Product p2 = target.Edit(2).ViewData.Model as Product;
Product p3 = target.Edit(3).ViewData.Model as Product;
Product result = (Product)target.Edit(4).ViewData.Model;
```

When I comment it, nothing changes.
I can't uderstand, where is NULL value.

Comment: When you hit `Edit` the proper `productId` more than likely isn't transmitted.  Modify the `int productId` to `int? productId`, then see if the parameter is indeed coming across as a `null`.  Which will let you either handle the `null` before continue or figure out why you aren't always passing a valid id to `Edit`.

Comment: You can try define `ProductID` as `int?` to make it nullable, in which case the assignment would work.

Comment: No @aevitas its a required parameter, its to edit a resource, do not make it nullable. Stop suggesting bad design.

Comment: @Phill Interestingly said bad design got accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action needs a parameter which is `int` and you are not passing it.if you put in browser **/Edit?ProductId=1`** it will work, or make action parameter null able.

```
public ViewResult Edit(int? ProductId)
```

now it will not throw error.

Comment: It helped. Thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in method declaration:

```
public ViewResult Edit(int productId)
```

You expecting productId, but not passing it: http://localhost:63843/Admin/Edit. URL should be: http://localhost:63843/Admin/Edit/1

Answer (score 1):

The null value comes from when you visit *http://localhost:63843/Admin/Edit* without specifying the `productId`, as in *http://localhost:63843/Admin/Edit?productId=1*.

You can make the `productId` optional by making it nullable:

```
public ViewResult Edit(int? productId) 
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your line

```
public ViewResult Edit(int productId) {
```

you have the parameter `productId` defined as `int`. The message tells no more than this must be a nullable parameter or an optional one. So just chage it either to

```
// nullable
public ViewResult Edit(int? productId) { ... }
```

or

```
// optional
public ViewResult Edit(int productId = -1) { ... }
```

so any call of `Edit` will accept an incoming `null` - regardless if this will happen or not.

---

What about make the parameter be an int? ans Set a breakpoint inside the function to analyse the stacktrace/ callhirarchy to find out who tried the null-call ..?

Comment: "The message tells no more than this must be a nullable parameter or an optional one." <-- no, the code is correct, its a required parameter, it should not be null or optional.

Comment: You are right and i didn't read the question carefull. I will extend my answere.